# How to do screen recording and save in some cloud storage like s3 in real time

Tags: node.js, go, stream, recording

I am trying to solve a problem where you need to record screens in real time and keep on sending the data to the backend which will store the video as an s3 object(any cloud store).

I did research it, but everywhere I see people are recording the video and send it as a single file after recording is completed, the problem here is the file may be very big to send it as a single file, hence I want it to get saved in real-time in s3.

I have also seen Webrtc which helps in peer to peer communication.

any suggestions around this to implement in GO or Nodejs will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is using an SFU. Which will be used to send screen data to using webrtc and save it to a file server-side.

You can use [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org) for this.

Here is a working example: https://github.com/ethand91/mediasoup3-record-demo

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Multipart upload overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html).

No matter how large the video will be, you only need to upload each 5M data as a part to S3. Although it doesn't work exactly like a stream, it's almost a stream.

For the GO sdk, please check [S3 Golang SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/)

Comment: It should work for you. I tried to implement a custom file stream. In the file stream, I call CreateMultipartUpload when the file is created. When the user writes data into the stream,  I cached the data until the size exceeds 5M, then I call UploadPart to upload the cached data. Finally, when the user closes the file stream, I will call CompleteMultipartUpload to finish the uploading.